# Page builder product carousel hide on changing the screen size issue Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, page-builder

On my website I added product carousel using page builder. But there is an issue, when I change the screen desktop to ipad or iphone and iphone to desktop in browser. Product Slider of home page gets hide.

Answer (score 0):

This below code helped me. Add this below code in your custom js file of your project.

```
    const $slider = $('.slick-slider'); 
        $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);
            }, 100);
```

You can check below link
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1808